# Python resource RLIMIT_NOFILE lists large limit for open files on Mac

Tags: python, macos, filehandle

The Python [resource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html) module can (I believe) tell you the open files limit.

On Linux this returns `(1024, 65536)` for the soft and hard limits.  I can verify the soft limit but the hard limit seems higher than I would expect my default to be.

On OS-X resource returns very high results:

```
In [1]: import resource

In [2]: resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
Out[2]: (7168, 9223372036854775807)
```

The high limit in particular seems unreasonably high.  In practice I find that OS-X machines tend to top out at around 128 open files.  What's going on here?

Comment: See https://github.com/roryk/ipython-cluster-helper/issues/18

Comment: Type `ulimit -H -n` in Terminal and it says unlimited. What you're seeing is `RLIM_INFINITY`.

Comment: How about the 7168 soft limit?

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: Just verifying that, by default, OS-X has a soft limit of 7168 open files

Comment: When I run `ulimit -n` on my Mac, it says 256. What do you see when you do that?